# react update state from children broke component at the same level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I am new to react. I'm trying to update the parent state from the child but i have an error on another component at the the same level of the child one.

that's my code.

RedirectPage.js (parent)

```
const RedirectPage = (props) => {

  const [status, setStatus] = useState("Loading");
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState(null);
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null)
  const [showLoader, setShowLoader] = useState(true)
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(false)
  const [isPlaylistCreated, setIsPlaylistCreated] = useState(false)
  
  const headers = getParamValues(props.location.hash)

  const getWeather = () =>{
    //fetch data..
    //...
    //...
      .then(response => {
        var res = response.json();
        return res;          
      })
      .then(result => {
        setWeather(result)
        setShowLoader(false)
        setStatus(null)
        setLocation(result.name)
      });
    })
  }

  const changeStateFromChild = (value) => {
    setIsPlaylistCreated(value)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getWeather()
  },[]);

  return (
    <div className="containerRedirectPage">
      {showLoader ? (
        <div className="wrapperLogo">
          <img src={loader}className="" alt="logo" />
        </div>)
         : (
        <div className="wrapperColonne">
          <div className="firstRow">
            <WeatherCard weatherConditions={weather}/>
          </div>
          {isPlaylistCreated ? (
            <div className="secondRow">
              <PlaylistCard />
            </div>
          ) : (
            <PlaylistButton userId={userId} headers={headers} weatherInfo={weather} playlistCreated={changeStateFromChild} />
          )}
          
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
};
export default RedirectPage;
```

PlaylistButton.js:

```
export default function PlaylistButton({userId, headers, weatherInfo, playlistCreated}) {

  const buttonClicked = async () => {

    // ...some code...

    playlistCreated(true) 

  }

  return (
    <div className="button-container-1">
      <span className="mas">CREA PLAYLIST</span>
      <button onClick={buttonClicked} id='work' type="button" name="Hover">CREA PLAYLIST</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and that's the other component i'm getting the error when i click on button.

WeatherCard.js:

```
const WeatherCard = ({weatherConditions}) => {

  const [weather, setWeather] = useState(null);    

  const [icon, setIcon] = useState(null);

  const getTheIcon = () => {
// code to get the right icon
    }
    setIcon(x)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getTheIcon()
  },[]);

  return (
    <div className="weatherCard">
      <div className="headerCard">
        <h2>{weatherConditions.name}</h2>
        <h3>{Math.floor(weatherConditions.main.temp)}°C</h3>
      </div>
      <div className="bodyCard">
        <h5>{weatherConditions.weather[0].description}</h5>
        <img  className="weatherIcon" src={icon} alt="aa" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};
export default WeatherCard;
```

the first time i load the redirect page WeatherCard component is right. When i click the button i get this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AcpA.png)

Can someone explain me why ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the effect of the setting `playlistCreated(true)` ?
Does it affects the weatherCondition object ?
If weatherCondition could be undefined at some point you need to check it before using its properties (name, main.temp, and weather)

Update:
The error clearly state that it cannot read name from weather because it's undefined. You have to check it before using the weather object properties.

```
 if (!weatherConditions) {
    return <div>Loading...</div> // or something appropriate.
 }
 return (
    <div className="weatherCard">
      <div className="headerCard">
        <h2>{weatherConditions.name}</h2>
        {weatherConditions.main && <h3>{Math.floor(weatherConditions.main.temp)}°C</h3>}
      </div>
      <div className="bodyCard">
        {weatherConditions.weather && 
        {weatherConditions.weather.length > 0 &&
        <h5>{weatherConditions.weather[0].description}</h5>}
     ....
  )
```

Comment: nope,  playlistCreated(true) does not have any affects on the weatherConditions object...

Comment: yes @AntonioPantano but  first time the page is loaded everything is right, WeatherCard is loaded correctly. 
The error is after the button clicked and nothing changed with the variable weather passed to the WeatherCard.
I can't understand

Comment: @Filippo To help you with this you should provide more code. It's hard to see what is going on there. Because you are getting the weather conditions asynchronously I don't see how at the first render the data are not undefined.